# c++ how does compiler get the length of argv strings

Tags: c++, c

In C/C++, argc is the count of command line arguments and argv is char** or pointer to pointer of characters. I get that argc can be used to get number of arguments, but how does the compiler know the length of the first argument or the second?

Comment: It doesn't.  That's stuff passed to your program from the OS

Comment: nul terminated string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all C strings, the strings that `argv` points to are 0-terminated.

The compiler doesn't know. (It can't. By the time the program is called with some actual arguments, the compiler is long done.) But the program can find out using `strlen`.

Answer (score 3):

The *compiler* doesn't know anything about the contents of `argv`.  The *runtime library* that is provided by your compiler vendor and linked to your executable will get the command-line arguments from the OS when the process is created, and that library will then allocate its own array of `char*` pointers to *null-terminated strings* that are copied from the OS-provided data.  That array is then passed to your `main()` via `argv`, and `argc` is set to the number of valid `char*` pointers in the array.  The runtime will free memory for that array after `main()` exits.

Answer (score 0):

The operating system normally puts all the parameters and the environment strings on the stack segment, just above the first stack frame for the function `main()`, then the `argv` array is also stacked and finally the `argc` variable is passed to `main()`.  As they are above `main()`'s stack frame, with the code that calls also your signal handlers in user space (the signal handlers do execute in user mode).  You are hidden all those things, as you don't need to know where they are.  This happens in linux and almost all unix derivatives.  The structure is something like:

- A structure that allows an external program to know where the parameter list and the environment starts, for accessing the top of the stack.
- Code to call signal handlers when the systems returns to user code and a signal handler needs to be called.  As the above structure is fixed in length, both things can be accessed by just knowing where the stack segment begun.
- All the environment strings.  This is variable length.
- All the command line parameters.  Also variable length.
- Two arrays of pointers, the first with pointers to the environment strings (in the form "variable_name=value") and the second to the command line arguments (both arrays are ended with and extra `NULL` pointer signalling the end of the array).
- A pointer reference to the environment (`envp`, legacy, C standard doesn't state that the environment can be accessed as a third parameter to `main()` but some legacy code assumes that, so I assume it's still being done so)
- A pointer reference to the command line array (`argc`)
- An `int` with the number of command line arguments of `argv`.
- the return value for `main()` to return.

The parameters to `main()` are normally accessed as the first and second parameters above the return pointer.

This is the way `main()` is called, and this is partially filled by the operating system (mainly the strings, the arrays, the signal handlers code and the first struct to locate the pointers to the parameters and the environment), before giving control to the runtime, partly filled by the C standard runtime (the `argc` parameter count, the `argv` pointer and the `envp` pointer).  And then `main()` is called, pushing the return address on the call to `main()`.

Just to say that this is only one possible implementation, and that no runtime is forced to do so, but it is so assumed from legacy code dating from the pdp-11 implementation, so it is still implemented that way in many platforms.

Check this program (it prints its command line arguments, and the environment):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    printf(
        "%14p: argc(=%d)\n"
        "%14p: argv\n"
        "%14p: envp\n",
        &argc, argc,
        &argv,
        &envp);

    printf(
        "%14p: argv[]\n"
        "%14p: envp[]\n",
        argv,
        envp);

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= argc; i++) {
        printf("%2$14p: argv[%1$d] => \"%2$s\"\n",
            i, argv[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; envp[i]; i++) {
        printf("%2$14p: envp[%1$d] => \"%2$s\"\n",
            i, envp[i]);
    }
    /* .. and NULL environment final pointer */
    printf("%2$14p: envp[%1$d] => \"%2$s\"\n",
        i, envp[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

And call it with different argument list, and see how it prints the argument list, then the environment strings.

This is the output on my system for a call:

```
$ a.out a b c | sort | less
           0x0: argv[4] => "(null)"
           0x0: envp[36] => "(null)"
0x7fffffffe368: envp
0x7fffffffe370: argv
0x7fffffffe378: argc(=4)
0x7fffffffe3f0: argv[]
0x7fffffffe418: envp[]
0x7fffffffe6f0: argv[0] => "pru72524"
0x7fffffffe6f9: argv[1] => "a"
0x7fffffffe6fb: argv[2] => "b"
0x7fffffffe6fd: argv[3] => "c"
0x7fffffffe6ff: envp[0] => "SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash"
0x7fffffffe719: envp[1] => "WINDOWID=18874381"
0x7fffffffe72b: envp[2] => "XTERM_VERSION=XTerm(354)"
0x7fffffffe744: envp[3] => "TERMCAP=SC|screen|VT 100/ANSI X3.64 virtual termin>
0x7fffffffeaed: envp[4] => "JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk8"
0x7fffffffeb0b: envp[5] => "SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-0ssuWLqLKLsr/agent.1659"
0x7fffffffeb3a: envp[6] => "WINDOW=6"
0x7fffffffeb43: envp[7] => "ANT_HOME=/usr/local/share/java/apache-ant"
0x7fffffffeb6d: envp[8] => "SSH_AGENT_PID=1660"
0x7fffffffeb80: envp[9] => "XTERM_SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash"
0x7fffffffeba0: envp[10] => "EDITOR=vi"
0x7fffffffebaa: envp[11] => "PWD=/home/lcu"
0x7fffffffebb8: envp[12] => "MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX=/home/lcu/obj"
0x7fffffffebd7: envp[13] => "LOGNAME=lcu"
0x7fffffffebe3: envp[14] => "TZ=Europe/Helsinki"
0x7fffffffebf6: envp[15] => "WINDOWPATH=9"
0x7fffffffec03: envp[16] => "LDFLAGS=-g"
0x7fffffffec0e: envp[17] => "HOME=/home/lcu"
0x7fffffffec1d: envp[18] => "LANG=es_ES.UTF-8"
0x7fffffffec2e: envp[19] => "XTERM_LOCALE=es_ES.UTF-8"
0x7fffffffec47: envp[20] => "TERM=screen"
0x7fffffffec53: envp[21] => "USER=lcu"
0x7fffffffec5c: envp[22] => "NETBEANS_HOME=/home/opt/netbeans"
0x7fffffffec7d: envp[23] => "MAVEN_HOME=/usr/local/share/java/maven"
0x7fffffffeca4: envp[24] => "DISPLAY=:0"
0x7fffffffecaf: envp[25] => "FORTUNE_PATH=/home/lcu/.fortune:/usr/share/games/>
0x7fffffffece8: envp[26] => "SHLVL=1"
0x7fffffffecf0: envp[27] => "PAGER=less -EFGRS"
0x7fffffffed02: envp[28] => "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/lcu/lib:/home/lcu/lib:"
0x7fffffffed2f: envp[29] => "MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx2048m"
0x7fffffffed44: envp[30] => "PATH=/home/lcu/bin:.:/usr/local/share/java/apache>
0x7fffffffef10: envp[31] => "STY=2430.pts-1.europa"
0x7fffffffef26: envp[32] => "BLOCKSIZE=K"
0x7fffffffef32: envp[33] => "CFLAGS=-g -O0 -DHAS_LIBUTIL_H"
0x7fffffffef50: envp[34] => "MAIL=/var/mail/lcu"
0x7fffffffef63: envp[35] => "_=./pru72524"
$ _
```